# Best way to convert a table to a data.frame?

Tags: r

Suppose one wants to have the frequency `table` as a `data.frame` object, what is the best way to convert it? I tried some ideas and came up with a convoluted solution and I'm wondering if there is a better way.

First we generate some data:

```
set.seed(1)
test_df = data.frame(X = sample(0:1, 100, T),
                     Y = sample(0:1, 100, T))
p = table(test_df)
p2 = prop.table(p)
```

I'm interested in the `prop.table()` output, but it applies equally to the frequency `table`. It looks like this:

```
> p2
   Y
X    0  1
  0 28 18
  1 34 20
```

`as.data.frame()` works but returns the result in long format:

```
> as.data.frame(p2)
  X Y Freq
1 0 0   28
2 1 0   34
3 0 1   18
4 1 1   20
```

`as.matrix()` does nothing:

```
> class(as.matrix(p2))
[1] "table"
```

Finally, a convoluted method that works:

```
prop_table = as.data.frame(matrix(as.vector(p2), nrow = 2))
colnames(prop_table) = rownames(prop_table) = rownames(p2)
```

Output:

```
> prop_table
   0  1
0 28 18
1 34 20
```

Better ideas?